# Why aren't Firebase Functions V2 available over the API or showing in the Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on migrating Firebase Functions V1 to V2 and I'm seeing some strange behaviour.

1. I cannot see the function in my firebase project in the Functions view.
2. I can see the function in the Google Cloud console. Clicking on the function name shows me an endpoint. However, when hitting this endpoint I get a 404: "The requested URL was not found on this server.".
3. If I click on the link below "Powered by Cloud Run" it gives a URL which I don't recongnise which as an endpoint is functional.
4. When accessing the functionName using the Swift Firebase SDK I don't also get the 404.

I've checked my versions for my packages and they are the following:

1. Firebase CLI: 12.4.3
2. Firebase Functions: 4.4.1
3. I've migrated the call for the firebase function to use the new `onCall` approach detailed in the documentation.
4. I've set the region to europe-west2 both through the `setGlobalOptions` method and in the option passed to `onCall`.
5. I've deployed the function using `firebase deploy --only functions:<functionName>` where  is the name of the function.